# is it possible to change to HTML root element style with js

Tags: javascript, css

Hi im trying to change to `font-size` of the whole HTML page currently i have in my css :

```
html {
  font-size : 65.5%
}
```

and im looking to mutate the value with JS for ex :

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('html').style.fontSize = '35%'
```

if that however is not possible please explain to me why and maybe provide a solution for this thanks

Comment: i know that i can use the fontSize on the body element

Comment: The easier way to do this is just document.body.style.fontSize = '35%';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` is grabbing an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) vs. a single element. `[0]` index it to grab the `html` tag and proceed with what you had:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.fontSize = '35%';
```

Alternatively, you could use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which would just select the first matching element:

```
document.querySelector('html').style.fontSize = '35%';
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way, slightly more concise:

```
document.documentElement.style.fontSize = '35%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Carl said, your code runs into an issue by expecting a single `<html>` element from `document.getElementsByTagName('html')`, but is instead getting a *collection* of elements. Carl's answer will help you resolve that problem.

There is still another problem you may encounter though: if you are trying to reduce all font sizes by applying a smaller font size to the root `<html>` element you will only succeed in effecting font-sizes *relative to the `<html>` element*! Setting `font-size: 20px;` will cause that element to *always* have `20px` font, no matter the font sizes of its ancestor elements.

We can see that some font sizes fail to change in the following example:

```css
/* We attempt to shrink all font sizes: */
html { font-size: 66%; }

/* These styles just make it easier to see what's happening */
div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
body > div { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
```

```html
**Html font-size: 66%**<br/><br/>
<div style="font-size: 100%">
  font-size: 100%;
</div>
<div style="font-size: 100%">
  font-size: 100%;
  <div style="font-size: 100%">
    font-size: 100%;
  </div>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 16px">
  font-size: 16px; (not effected by html font-size!)
</div>
<div style="font-size: 16px">
  font-size: 16px; (not effected by html font-size!)
  <div style="font-size: 100%">
    font-size: 100%; (not effected by html font-size!)
  </div>
</div>
```

Following Carl's advice, and making sure all font-sizes in your page are relative, will give you the results you want!